# Else If - Google Script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

this script was working before on my Google Sheet, then all of a sudden, it stopped working. I notice that the first argument (if) is working, but all the codes after that is not working. Any ideas?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Sheet1
  // target sheet of move to named Sheet2
  // test column with yes is col 7 or G
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Under Contract Response Form" && r.getColumn() == 7 && (r.getValue() == "Closed" || r.getValue() == "Expired" || r.getValue() == "Cancelled")) {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed/Expired & Cancelled");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Listing Response Form" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Pending" ) {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Under Contract Response Form");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
   } else if(s.getName() == "Listing Response Form" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Cancelled" ) {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed/Expired & Cancelled");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Under Contract Response Form" && r.getColumn() == 7 && (r.getValue() == "Pre-list" || r.getValue() == "Withheld" || r.getValue() == "Coming Soon" || r.getValue() == "Active")) {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Listing Response Form");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Closed/Expired & Cancelled" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "Pending" ) {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Under Contract Response Form");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve]. In this specific include the sheets names andd add `console.log` statements. Also please bear in mind that `getActive...` methods on 
 on edit triggers might cause problems, specially if the user is not waiting for the script to finish it's execution before activating another range.

Answer (score 0):

The script looks fine, so chances are that one or more sheets has been renamed, or columns inserted or deleted. Check the sheet names and look for things like leading or trailing spaces. Also ensure that the values that should trigger row move appear in column G.

You can make row moves more robust by using column *names* instead of column *numbers*. See the [moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/39992635?msgid=40432488) script.